# Callbacks order in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, input-formats

I have 2 modules (filters): `html_pre_filter` and `syntaxhighlighter`.

`syntaxhighlighter_prepare_callback` executes before `html_pre_filter_prepare_callback`.

How to reoder them?

I tried this

```
function html_pre_filter_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook)
{
    if($hook == 'filter_prepare')
    {
    $group = $implementations ['syntaxhighlighter'];
    unset($implementations ['syntaxhighlighter']);
    $implementations ['syntaxhighlighter'] = $group;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: wait, can't you just drag&drop filters in text format settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are trying doesn't work because `syntaxhighlighter_prepare_callback()` and `html_pre_filter_prepare_callback()` are not hooks: They are simply callback functions defined in the implementation of [`hook_filter_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7) done from those modules.

In fact, the code used by [`check_markup()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/check_markup/7) to invoke the input format filters is the following one.

```
  // Get a complete list of filters, ordered properly.
  $filters = filter_list_format($format->format);
  $filter_info = filter_get_filters();

  // Give filters the chance to escape HTML-like data such as code or formulas.
  foreach ($filters as $name => $filter) {
    if ($filter->status && isset($filter_info [$name]['prepare callback']) && function_exists($filter_info [$name]['prepare callback'])) {
      $function = $filter_info [$name]['prepare callback'];
      $text = $function($text, $filter, $format, $langcode, $cache, $cache_id);
    }
  }

  // Perform filtering.
  foreach ($filters as $name => $filter) {
    if ($filter->status && isset($filter_info [$name]['process callback']) && function_exists($filter_info [$name]['process callback'])) {
      $function = $filter_info [$name]['process callback'];
      $text = $function($text, $filter, $format, $langcode, $cache, $cache_id);
    }
  }
```

No hook is invoked, or you would see a call to `module_invoke()` or similar function.

If you are looking at a way to programmatically re-order filters used by input formats, the only way I can see is altering the cache where Drupal stores the information about the input filters. See [`filter_list_format()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/filter_list_format/7), which is the function that returns an ordered list of filters used by an input format.
More easily, this can be accomplished from the user interface, since on admin/config/content/formats you order the input filter for each input format.